# How should I use ivy in a CI environment?

Tags: continuous-integration, ivy, dependency-management

I am using ant and Apache Ivy, and i have multiple plans in my CI server building the same source code, executing different types of tests.

Ivy must be deleting myorg-myproject-runtime.xml file in my cache and recreating it because the CI build plans are being executed so many times.

Eventually one of the CI build plans reads the file while it has been generated and results in my builds failing and this error is shown in the logs..

> /build-dir/my-ivy.xml:47: impossible
>   to ivy retrieve:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: problem
>   during retrieve of [ myorg| myproject
>   ]: java.text.ParseException: failed to
>   parse report:
>   ../../repo/cache/myorg-myproject-runtime.xml:
>   Premature end of file.

Is there a way to avoid this, using ivy in a CI environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found my answer.

By using a separate ivy cache for each build plan, ivy does not overwrite it's own *-runtime.xml file.

Works for me.